# How to implement Sass into a React App which uses bundle.js / bundle.css

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, bundle

I am working on a React project which uses bundle.js / bundle.css.
They are linked in the index.html like this:

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bundle.css" />
```

So far I wrote my CSS code into the "client/style.css" file and it worked.

Now I want to implement Sass/scss. I already did this:

- I installed Dart Sass and it is in my devDependencies:  `"sass": "^1.32.8"`
- I created a "main.scss" file and copy-pasted my CSS code into it.
- In package.json I wrote this script to compile the scss into css:
  `"compile:sass": "sass client/sass/main.scss client/style.comp.css"`
- In the command line I ran this script: `compile:sass`
- This created two files next to my "style.css" -> "style.comp.css" and "style.comp.css.map"

In "style.comp.css" I can see the compiled styles. However, they do not get applied in the browser. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question I actually found a solution. I am not sure if it is the best solution, but it works :) Please feel free to add your answers, in case you have a better solution, or more information.

I guess my problem was caused by bundle.css which was looking for changes in "style.css".

- I realized that in my "scripts" in "package.json" I wrote this:
  `"compile:sass": "sass client/sass/main.scss client/style.comp.css"`
- I deleted the "comp." in the latter file name, which is the file name where the scss code should be compiled:
  `"compile:sass": "sass client/sass/main.scss client/style.css"`

I deleted the two previously created files "style.comp.css" and "style.comp.css.map" and run this command in the Terminal again:

- `compile:sass`

Bingo - the code was compiled in "style.css" and was rendered properly in the browser.

---

Additionally, I would like to add this helpful and related information:

If you leave the code like this, you will have to run this command again and again to see any saved changes `compile:sass`.

Thus, I added this script: `"watch:sass": "sass client/sass/main.scss client/style.css --watch",`

If you then run this command in the Terminal, it will automatically detect changes and rerender the browser: `watch:sass`.

Hope this helps! If there are much better solutions, I will upvote them / mark them as the best solution / edit them into this answer.